# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte - Euro Symbol

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, character-encoding

I build a connection to the Google Finance API which gives me stock quotes. Everything is working fine until I switch to courses from Europe. These contain the € Symbol and I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\getQuotes.py", line 32, in <module>
    quote = c.get("SAP","FRA")
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\getQuotes.py", line 21, in get
    obj = json.loads(content[3:])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 381, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

The following is the code I am using. I guess that the error appears while the json is trying to processing the string but he can not resolve the euro symbol:

```
import urllib2
import json
import time

class GoogleFinanceAPI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prefix = "http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q="

    def get(self,symbol,exchange):
        url = self.prefix+"%s:%s"%(exchange,symbol)
        u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        content = u.read()

        obj = json.loads(content[3:])
        return obj[0]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = GoogleFinanceAPI()

    while 1:
        quote = c.get("MSFT","NASDAQ")
        print quote
        time.sleep(30)
```

This is how it Google Finance gives me the output for the SAP Stock containing the Euro symbol:

```
// [ { "id": "8424920" ,"t" : "SAP" ,"e" : "FRA" ,"l" : "56.51" ,"l_cur" : "€56.51" ,"s": "0" ,"ltt":"8:00PM GMT+2" ,"lt" : "Aug 7, 8:00PM GMT+2" ,"c" : "-0.47" ,"cp" : "-0.82" ,"ccol" : "chr" } ]
```

I tried to use this function and instead of the opener the (content[3:]) part but with this I got the same error, also that instead of an utf-8 I got an ascii error.

```
json.loads(unicode(opener.open(...), "ISO-8859-15"))
```

If someone has an idea I would be very happy.

Comment: interestingly, that resources returns `charset=ISO-8859-1`.  Clearly a lie.  It even "honors" the `Accept-Charset` request header, but that has no effect on the response entity, it's `0x80` no matter what charset the headers insist it must be.  I would regard this as a bug in the finance.google.com service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document you're fetching appears to be encoded with Windows Codepage 1252, where the euro sign character is encoded as `\x80`. That's an invalid byte in UTF-8 and a non-printing control character in all the ISO-8859 variants. Try:

```
obj = json.loads(content[3:], 'cp1252')
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. Sometimes these encodings are pretty tough ones.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, the Google Finance API is returning code page 1252 data. You can find out that it has done so my looking at the `Content-Type` header:

```
>>> u= urllib2.urlopen('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=SAP:FRA')
>>> u.headers['Content-Type']
'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'
```

(In the `text/html` world, ISO-8859-1 really means Windows code page 1252, for tedious historical reasons. There are a few others for different locales. Goodness knows why Google are returning `text/html` for what is blatantly not an HTML resource though mind...)

But you don't really want code page 1252, even if you can decode it using `json.loads(..., 'windows-1252')`—it's a weird encoding for JSON, and who knows what'll happen for other currency symbols not available in that encoding.

If I view the same URL in a browser, I get proper UTF-8 result. Why? Seems Google is UA-sniffing. Set a UA header to get the encoding you want:

```
>>> u= urllib2.urlopen('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=SAP:FRA', headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
>>> u.headers['Content-Type']
'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
```

**BAD GOOGLE**